# ERROR ** Assertion failed in Wijmo: Number expected. Error

Tags: angular, typescript, wijmo, wijmo-grid

I am using wijmo flex grid I am getting below error.

```
Assertion failed in Wijmo: Number expected. Error  
Assertion failed in Wijmo: Number expected. Error 
Assertion failed in Wijmo: Number expected. Error
```

I am able to bind wijmo flex grid, but showing above error in console.`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, and the way I solved it was by ensuring that my column definition controls 'wj-flex-grid-column' in html were receiving the width property as a number type value, following this example from their intro guide:
[wj-flex-grid-column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rA0lF.png)

Hope that helps you and solves your problem!!
https://demos.wijmo.com/5/angular2/flexgridintro/flexgridintro/